# What's the purpose of multi-threaded apartments?

Tags: windows, com

I understand the reason behind STA, but don't really see the reason for MTA.

A COM object can be loaded without any apartments, right? That means it's already able to take calls asynchronously, since no one puts any constraints.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: STA is a historical COM feature (with lot of code from Windows to support it and sometimes lots of pain for the developer to use it) that gives multi-threading for free w/o much work from the developer. MTA is kinda the opposite, ie, it's a non feature.

Comment: MTA = faster. Nothing is serialized unless you do it manually. STA = a free feature if you don't want to mess with synchronization.

Comment: MTA is not inherently faster than STA. You don't have serialization if you use STA on the same thread that created the apartment.

Comment: @SimonMourier though I still don't get it: what is it MTA doing? From what I know, it is one apartment that spawns threads(I don't know what it actually means). But why do you need this weird thing as "apartment" for something(multi-threading) that doesn't bring anything to the table. I mean, it's same as if there was no such  thing as MTA. So, it means 'MTA = no STA', just something to confuse the folk?

Comment: Think of MTA as basically doing nothing, that's why I said it's a non feature. The real question is more "what's the purpose of STA" ? The COM apartment threading model (single, apartment, both) was created more than 20 years ago so initially desktop single threaded apps (such as VB apps) would support multi-threading (including server apps) w/o too much weird bugs.

Comment: The MTA is not necessarily alone in a process, the process can have additional STAs. In that case there would be serialization between the MTA and any given STA. So basically the MTA contains the threads that can't directly call any STA.

Usually you do have at least one STA, because the user interface wants to be single threaded.

Comment: The thing that has no features still needs a name so you can talk about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your assumption is wrong: a COM object can *not* be created outside of any apartment.  Generally a thread should only create COM objects if it has previously called CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx, which places it in an apartment. Otherwise, creation will usually fail. There is the edge case of the implicit multithreaded apartment (if another thread of the same process initialized it), but even then you would be in the MTA, just in an unreliable and hard to debug way. No COM object ever exists without being in an apartment.

The reason you want an MTA is that it is not necessarily the only apartment. A process can have one MTA and arbitrarily many STAs. Calls between the MTA and any of the STAs still need to be marshaled; if they weren't, one of the MTA threads could call an STA thread in an unsafe way.

In fact having at least one STA is the rule rather than the exception: The user interface wants to live in an STA, because it depends on messages (for example because of mouse clicks etc.) to be processed in sequence.